# LINQ to SQL query against a list of entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Ingredient class:

```
class Ingredient
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

List of Ingredients:

```
var ingredientsList = new List<Ingredient>();
```

Database layout of my "Ingredients" table:

```
[Ingredients] (
    [IngredientsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RecipeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IngredientsName] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [IngredientsAmount] [float] NOT NULL
)
```

Am I able to query my `ingredientsList` against my "Ingredients" table, doing a where-clause which goes something like this (pseudo code alert!):

```
SELECT * FROM Ingredients WHERE
IngredientsName = ["Name" property on entities in my ingredientsList] AND
IngredientsAmount <= ["Amount" property on entities in my ingredientsList]
```

I of course want this to be done with LINQ, and not using dynamically generated SQL queries.

Comment: I originally thought Linq could handle joining two types of entities until I tried it

Comment: What's exactly the result you want to get? I don't really understand that "query my ingredientsList against my "Ingredients" table" part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ is composable, but to do this without using UNION you'd have to roll your own `Expression`. Basically, we (presumably) want to create TSQL of the form:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [table]
WHERE  (Name = @name1 AND Amount <= @amount1)
OR     (Name = @name2 AND Amount <= @amount2)
OR     (Name = @name3 AND Amount <= @amount3)
...
```

where the name/amount pairs are determined at runtime. There is easy way of phrasing that in LINQ; if it was "AND" each time, we could use `.Where(...)` repeatedly. `Union` is a candidate, but I've seen repeated people have problems with that. What we want to do is emulate us writing a LINQ query like:

```
var qry = from i in db.Ingredients
          where (  (i.Name == name1 && i.Amount <= amount1)
                || (i.Name == name2 && i.Amount <= amount2)
                ... )
          select i;
```

This is done by crafting an `Expression`, using `Expression.OrElse` to combine each - so we will need to iterate over our name/amount pairs, making a richer `Expression`.

Writing `Expression` code by hand is a bit of a black art, but I have a very similar example up my sleeve (from a presentation I give); it uses some custom extension methods; usage via:

```
    IQueryable query = db.Ingredients.WhereTrueForAny(
        localIngredient => dbIngredient =>
                   dbIngredient.Name == localIngredient.Name
                && dbIngredient.Amount <= localIngredient.Amount
            , args);
```

where `args` is your array of test ingredients. What this does is: for each `localIngredient` in `args` (our local array of test ingredients), it asks us to provide an `Expression` (for that `localIngredient`) that is the test to apply at the database. It then combines these (in turn) with `Expression.OrElse`:

---

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereTrueForAny<TSource, TValue>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Func<TValue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>> selector,
    params TValue[] values)
{
    return source.Where(BuildTrueForAny(selector, values));
}
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> BuildTrueForAny<TSource, TValue>(
    Func<TValue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>> selector,
    params TValue[] values)
{
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    // if there are no filters, return nothing
    if (values.Length == 0) return x => false;
    // if there is 1 filter, use it directly
    if (values.Length == 1) return selector(values[0]);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    // start with the first filter
    Expression body = Expression.Invoke(selector(values[0]), param);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    { // for 2nd, 3rd, etc - use OrElse for that filter
        body = Expression.OrElse(body,
            Expression.Invoke(selector(values[i]), param));
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

Comment: 20 minutes spent looking at your answer--trying to decipher your code. Still non-the-wiser. Could I talk you into trying to be a bit more explicit? Adding a few comments, explaining what your code does, perhaps?

Comment: Marc, you are making my head hurt!.. Not that I don't appreciate your efforts in educating me.. But damn!.. Could you spell it out for me - so to say - using my exact code combined with your WhereTrueForAny() method? :)

Comment: This looks awesome but trying to use it in Entity Framework 4.1 I get the error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."  Have you done this in EF at all?

Comment: @Nick the question was L2S which *does* support that. You can, however, remove the Invoke by using an ExpressionVisitor to translate the expression-tree. I've got a few examples of that kicking around on SO.

Answer (score 5):

The only extent to which you can use a local collection in a LINQ 2 SQL query is with the `Contains()` function, which is basically a translation to the SQL `in` clause. For example...

```
var ingredientsList = new List<Ingredient>();

... add your ingredients

var myQuery = (from ingredient in context.Ingredients where ingredientsList.Select(i => i.Name).Contains(ingredient.Name) select ingredient);
```

This would generate SQL equivalent to "`...where ingredients.Name in (...)`"

Unfortunately I don't think that's going to work for you, as you'd have to join each column atomically.

And just as an aside, using LINQ 2 SQL *is* a dynamically generated SQL query.

You could, of course, do the joining on the client side, but that would require bringing back the entire `Ingredients` table, which could be performance-prohibitive, and is **definitely** bad practice.

Comment: Well, if I'm understanding this right: this is actually an optimization. I could split this up in two parts: query ingredients against my collections names, then check if the amount of the ingredients is what I want it to be (in memory). Or am I way off? :)

Comment: You could do that, yes. I'm not entirely certain of what you're aiming at with this query, but from a technical perspective you could do that. In fact, if validation is what you're after then that would likely be more effective than the query you descrive in the question.

Comment: That was supposed to be "describe" for the English speakers in our audience.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll either have to use multiple queries, or copy your ingredients list into a temporary table and do the database query in that way.

I mean, you *could* have a SQL statement of:

```
SELECT * FROM Ingredients WHERE
(IngredientsName = 'Flour' AND IngredientsAmount < 10) OR   
(IngredientsName = 'Water' AND IngredientsAmount <= 5) OR
(IngredientsName = 'Eggs' AND IngredientsAmount <= 20)
```

but it get ugly pretty quickly.

Personally I suspect that the temporary table solution is going to be the neatest - but I don't know whether LINQ to SQL has much support for them.

Comment: Selecting all entries in a table sounds like a pretty bad choice, performance-wise. Also; I'm aiming at using LINQ to SQL for this. Not dynamically generated SQL queries :)

Comment: @rooster, like I said in my answer, LINQ 2 SQL is a dynamically-generated SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> ingredientNames = ingredientsList
  .Select( i => i.Name).ToList();
Dictionary<string, Double> ingredientValues = ingredientsList
  .ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i.Amount);
//database hit
List<Ingredient> queryResults = db.Ingredients
  .Where(i => ingredientNames.Contains(i.Name))
  .ToList();
//continue filtering locally - TODO: handle case-sensitivity
List<Ingredient> filteredResults = queryResults
  .Where(i => i.Amount <= ingredientValues[i.Name])
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with this solution in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net), if you have it, you can see the dump outputs.  Not sure if it is what you need, but from what I understand it is.  I used it against my `Users` table, but you could replaced that for Ingredients and "UserList" for "IngredientList" and "Username" for "Ingredient Name".  You can add further "OR" filtering expressions inside the if statement.  It is important you set an ID though.

So final note the "`Dump()`" method is specific to LINQPad and is not required.

```
var userList = new List<User>();
userList.Add(new User() { ID = 1, Username = "goneale" });
userList.Add(new User() { ID = 2, Username = "Test" });

List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
//                       vv ingredients from db context
IQueryable<User> users = Users;
foreach(var user in userList)
{
    if (users.Any(x => x.Username == user.Username))
        IDs.Add(user.ID);
}
IDs.Dump();
userList.Dump();
users.Dump();
users = users.Where(x => IDs.Contains(x.ID));
users.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Union to concatinate results of each subquery:

```
 public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereTrueForAny<TSource, TValue>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TValue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>> selector, params TValue[] values)
    {
        // code is based on Marc Gravells answer
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

        // if there are no filters, return nothing
        if (values.Length == 0) return source.Where(x => false);
        // if there is 1 filter, use it directly
        if (values.Length == 1) return source.Where(selector(values[0]));

        var lockingUpArray = values;

        var p = lockingUpArray.First();

        IQueryable<TSource> query = source.Where(selector(p));

        foreach (var param in lockingUpArray.Skip(1))
        {
            query = query.Union(source.Where(selector(param)));
        }

        return query;
    }
```