# LINQ to SQL: Advanced queries against lists, arrays and lists of objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**Single and multiple lists**

Consider the following lists:

```
List<Int32> appleIdentities = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
List<Int32> chocolateIdentities = new List<int>(new[] { 2, 3, 4 });
List<Int32> icecreamIdentities = new List<int>(new[] { 11, 14, 15, 16 });
```

Using LINQ to SQL; is it possible to wite a statement which translates into:

```
SELECT
    DesertsID,
    DesertsName
FROM
    Deserts
WHERE
    Deserts.AppleIdentity IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    Deserts.ChocolateIdentity IN (2, 3, 4) AND
    Deserts.IcecreamIdentity IN (11, 14, 15m 16)
```

If yes; how would the code look if I wanted to query my database of deserts against just the `appleIdentities` list?




**Arrays**

Consider the following arrays:

```
Int32[] appleIdentities = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
String[] chocolateNames = new[] {"Light", "Dark"};
```

Using LINQ to SQL; is it possible to wite a statement which translates into:

```
SELECT
    DesertsID,
    DesertsName
FROM
    Deserts
WHERE
    Deserts.AppleIdentity IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    Deserts.ChocolateName IN ('Light', 'Dark')
```

If yes; how would the code look if I wanted to query my database of deserts against just the `appleIdentities` array?




**List of objects**

Consider the following:

```
public class Identities
{
    public Int32 appleIdentity { get; set; }
    public String chokolateName { get; set; }
}

List<Identities> identities = new List<Identities>(new[] {
    new Identities { appleIdentity = 1, chokolateName = "Light" },
    new Identities { appleIdentity = 2, chokolateName = "Dark" },
});
```

Using LINQ to SQL; is it possible to wite a statement which translates into:

```
SELECT
    DesertsID,
    DesertsName
FROM
    Deserts
WHERE
    Deserts.AppleIdentity IN (1, 2) AND
    Deserts.ChocolateName IN ('Light', 'Dark')
```

If yes; how would the code look if I wanted to query my database of deserts against just the `appleIdentity`-property on my list of `Identities` objects?



This is branch off of [LINQ to SQL query against a list of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729899/linq-to-sql-query-against-a-list-of-entities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - just use `Contains` - using Northwind as an example:

```
var qry = from cust in ctx.Customers
          where custIds.Contains(cust.CustomerID)
             && regions.Contains(cust.Region)
          select cust; // or your custom projection
```

Answer (score 3):

> how would the code look if I wanted to
>   query my database of deserts against
>   just the appleIdentities list?

You can compose a linq query in multiple statements, like so, and select at runtime which filters your want to use in your where clause.

```
var query = db.Desserts;
if (filterbyAppleIdentity)
    query = query.Where( q => appleIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID));
if (filterbyChocolateIdentities)
    query = query.Where( q => chocolateIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID));
if (filterbicecreamIdentities)
    query = query.Where( q => icecreamIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID));

var deserts = query.ToList();
```

you can also write an extension method to do this without if statements: (Edit fixed typo, return type should be IQueriable

```
public static class LinqExtensions {
  public IQueriable<T> CondWhere<T>(this IQueriable<T> query, bool condition, Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) {
     if (condition)
        return query.Where(predicate);
     else 
        return query;
  }
 }
```

and write your linq query like this:

```
  var deserts = db.Desserts;
      .CondWhere(filterbyAppleIdentity, q => appleIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID));
      .CondWhere(filterbyChocolateIdentities, q => chocolateIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID));
      .CondWhere(filterbicecreamIdentities, q => icecreamIdentities.Contains(q.DesertsID)).ToList();
```

Another way to do it is to union the id lists:

```
var deserts = db.Deserts
        .Where( d => appleIdentities.Union(chocolateIdentities).Union(icecreamIdentities).Contains(d.DesertsID);
```

For a list of objects you can use .Select extension method to project your list into a int or string IEnumerable and you can use contains in the query in the same way:

```
var deserts = db.Deserts
    .Where(d => 
        identities.Select(i => i.appleIdentity).Contains(d => d.DesertID) &&
        identities.Select(i => i.chokolateName).Contains(d => d.DesertsName)
     )
```

Comment: Why the downvote? can you explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hear hear! Never down-vote without giving feedback. Not exactly constructive :/

Comment: I re-up voted you for your effort. I guess because they feel it can be done with Contains.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try:

```
var query = from dessert in db.Desserts
            where appleIdentities.Contains(dessert.AppleIdentity)
               && chocolateIdentities.Contains(dessert.ChocolateIdentity)
               && iceCreamIdentities.Contains(dessert.IceCreamIdentity)
            select new { dessert.Id, dessert.Name };
```

I believe that's okay, although it'll fail when the lists get big enough IIRC. That should be okay for lists and arrays.

I'm not sure about your third query though - I think you'd need a list for each of the separate Contains calls.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, LinqToSql will translate `Contains` to `IN`.

There's some caveats:

- this translation works for `List<T>.Contains()`, but doesn't work for `IList<T>.Contains()`.  Does it work for arrays?  I don't know.
- This translation will happily translate as many elements as you like - each element becomes a sql parameter.  SQL Server 2008 has an approx 2000 parameter limit and *will throw sql exceptions* at you if you try this with a collection that is too big.
- This translation, when applied to a collection of strings, will produce **nvarchar** parameters.  This could be a serious problem if the target column is **varchar** and you want to use the index on this column.  Sql Server will *convert the index*, instead of the parameters... which involves reading and converting every string in the whole index.

Here's some code for your **List of Objects** question:

```
List<int> someIDs = identities
   .Select(x => x.appleIdentity).ToList();
List<string> someStrings = identities
   .Select(x => x.chokolateName).ToList();

var query = db.Desserts.Where(d =>
  someIDs.Contains(d.AppleIdentity) &&
  someStrings.Contains(d.ChocolateName)
  )
```